# ATTINY85 and POT

Tags: potentiometer, attiny85

I need to read a potentiometer value from an ATTINY85.
I have big fat 10K POT but for this use case I need it to be very small so I used a salvaged 2.4K one, the kind that is soldered directly onto a PCB.

I am using tinkercad to prototype my project and I am facing a very weird problem. Everytime I read from the POT Pin, I get the value of 512 (using the debugger)

Here is a screenshot of my prototype:
[image]

The goal is to power the circuit and the lamp (does not matter what is there, consider it just a load) with a 9V battery, use a 5V regulator to power the ATTINY85 and use an NPN transistor to turn the lamp/load on or off.

For information, the whole regulator and transistor setup is tested and works like a charm.

Here is the code I wrote for the this case:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(PB0, INPUT);
}

int potValue = 0;

void loop()
{
  potValue = analogRead(PB0);
  delay(100);
}
```

Not real fancy right?
Now no matter what use for the POT, and I tried 2.4K, 10K and up to 100K, the value read by the ATTINY is always 512.

Do you see something wrong in this setup?
Could it be a bug in tinkercad? (I'd be surprised though)

I could try and share this circuit within tinkercad if someone would be willing to have a look...

EDIT: I just tried with PB2 as suggested but not the value is always 58:
[image]

Comment: Since you never display the reading from the pot, how do you know what it is?   Try printing it.

Comment: [Port PB0 is not an ADC pin on the ATTiny85](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf). Choose PB2, PB3, PB4 or PB5.

Comment: I know the value of the pot reading because tinkercad has a debugger

Comment: I'll try another pin straight away

Comment: I see you have a wire bridging the ground on one side of your breadboard to the other side. Don't you also need to bridge the +5V rail between sides of the breadboard? (in addition to using an analog pin.)

Comment: @DuncanC no as the input from the top rail is 9v and I use the 5v regulator to power the lower rail and the ATTINY85. Ground is common however

Comment: Note that you would need a resistor on the base of the NPN transistor.

Comment: Why do you think you need a smaller value pot? The resistance of the pot makes almost no difference to the readings the Arduino makes. It only has an effect when you go to very large (>1MΩ) values. By reducing to a smaller number all you're doing is wasting power.

Comment: When I way that I need a smaller POT I meant that the physical object needs to be smaller than the 10K one I have as I need to have an end result as small as possible, no relationship to the POT resistance at all, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Here it does not make a difference, but the PXn notation is no the same as a pin number, which gets used by Arduino functions. PB1 will be defined as 1, because it is the second bit in the registers for Port B (start counting from 0). So on a bigger microcontroller PC1 will also be 1. Pin numbers are different and on the Attiny85 just happen to be the same (because of the low pin number)

Comment: Did you see the comment of Edgar Bonet? You need a resistor at the base of the transistor. You _must_ limit the current through the base in order not to destroy the transistor or the ATTINY.  If I had to switch a load with an ATTINY I would use a MOSFET because they have a very high  input impedance (resistance) on the gate (base) pin. So the ATTINY pin won't be stressed. ;-)

Comment: I indeed saw the comment and actually used a resistor in my real life circuit. However I read that the resistor is mainly used to control the output value. So I kind of fail to understand how/why it is that could destroy either part. FYI I used a 1k resistor, no clue if that's enough. I looked through the documentation on my transistor but did not managed to find the info

Comment: @GeorgesLegros The transistor is like a diode between the base and the emitter. That means, that the current through it rises exponentially with the voltage. It can esaily exceed the max current of 20mA (and also the absolute maximum of 40mA) and thus destroy the digitial output hardware of that pin. A resistor reduces that current, so that is does not get blown. With 20mA max and 5V you could use 5V/20mA=250 Ohm to be safe, even, when the transistor would be shorted. Raise the value as you like, be careful with lower values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes more sense now. In my circuit I am switching a 9v input with the transistor, does that mean I should then have a minimum value of 450 Ohm for that resistor? In other words, should I base that calculation on the ATTINY and thus the pin or on the current I am switching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Port PB0 is not an ADC (analog input) pin on the ATTiny85](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf).

Available pins of the ATTiny85 (from the Atmel ATtiny 25, 45, 85 datasheet):

[image: ATtinyx5 pinout]Choose PB2, PB3, PB4 or PB5 if you need an analog input.

Additional information: When built in TinkerCAD, using PB2 as an analog input does not seem to work correctly and produces a fixed value. Using PB3 did work correctly however. This might be a bug in TinkerCAD.

Comment: Just tried and I get another weird fixed value: 58...

Comment: I edited the question so I could upload a picture of the new setup using PB2 and the debugger output

Comment: Just for fun, I built the same circuit (but simplified) in TinkerCAD and strangely enough I could not get it to work with PB2, but PB3 did work. I guess this is a bug in TinkerCAD. I haven't used it before until today but I'm pretty sure I've built it correctly.

Comment: Indeed, it works like a charm with PB3! Thanks! Can you add this comment to your answer so I can accept it (I guess it is clearer for future references)

Comment: I've added the comment to my answer.

Comment: I tried PB5 on tinkercad and it just getting "random" values event if I don't touch the POT. I shall send an email to the support just to let them know. However, do you confirm that it "should" work ok PB2? I'll do some tests on my breadboard to validate. Problem is that the real use case is actually making use of PB3 already...

Comment: PB5 is probably preconfigured as a RESET pin so I'm not sure it's wise to use it for anything other than that. I am not too familiar with the Analog part of the ATtiny's but I do know that (just like other AVRs) there's only a single A/D converter that the 4 analog inputs are connected to via an analog multiplexer and it should not make a difference what input pin is used (as long as it is not used for anything else).

Comment: That image can be a bit confusing if you don't know what to look for. Look at the pins that have ADC0, ADC1, ADC2, ADC3 next to them. As is `Analog to Digital Converter <number>`.

Comment: Just made another test and it seems like PB4 is also creating a problem as I get the same randomness as I was having with PB5 (RESET). I opened a support ticket with Tinkercad, looking forward to the answer, will keep you posted.